# How to return an Image to browser in rest API in JAVA from folder?

Tags: java, rest

I have a folder in my NetBeans project with images. I have a H2 database with a "properties" table.

The images are named after a column in the properties table for convenience. This is my code so far.

```
@PostMapping(value = "/image/large/{id}", produces = MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Image> getPicture(@PathVariable long id)throws Exception{
    System.out.println(id);
                //System.out.println(barcode);
                
    Properties prop1 = new Properties();
    prop1 = propService.findOne(id);
    
    String filepath = prop1.getPhoto();
    
    String img = "static/images/"+filepath;
    
    return img;
}
```

How can I implement this in my rest controller? Struggling to find a correct way to implement this, any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From the code you have provided, you can return a string representing an image location or path. This path can then be used in am image `<img />` tag.

The second option is to read your file using an inputstream and convert the image to base46 (which you then return to the client).